# How can I have get the version control of a folder in java coding?

Tags: java, file, version-control, directory

I have folder and subfolders in it. I want to maintain the version control of the folders and subfolders. In the mean time I want to have those details in my MySQL database using java program.

**My current plan:**

```
I'll have user interface and upload the files and store the same in the folders 
and also save the details such as filename, uploadeduser, filesize, uploadedtime, 
modifiedtime in the database. If the same file is edited, i'll add another     
one row with new values in uploadeduser and modifiedtime.
```

I don't know whether my approach is good or not.

If not, tell me the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage the versions of java code (but source code in general) is to use a version control tool (or SCM) tool. There are [many open source version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_version_control_software) tools to do so among which [git](https://git-scm.com/) and [subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) are the most common.

In order to use one of them you need to install a server (on your local machine or, better, on a remote machine) and then to install a client on your machine and to learn the minimal commands to start with. If your code is open source you can find many providers which offers free servers (e.g.: [github](https://github.com/)).

Comment: Yes you are right. I can have version control as you said for java source code. But my requirement is to have a version control for a particular folder and its sub-folders. Also I need to get the version control details in my java code.

Comment: Using a version control tool you can manage versions of a particular folder and its subfolders. All the information you need are already available in a scm tool, if you want to save them in a repository you can develop a plugin to the scm (e.g. svn provides the possibility to implements hooks which are programs triggered by some repository event, such as the creation of a new revision or the modification of an unversioned property or a new  commit).